# Representing number $X$ in base $r$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

In  general,    let $X = (X_{n−1}X_{n−2}...X_0)_r$        be  an  n-digit number  in  base    r.  Give    an  algorithm   or  explain in English  how to  represent   $X$        in  base    $r^2$.

I don't understand the question at all. If someone can give examples that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

One hundred in base $10$: $(100)_{10}=1(10^2)+0(10)+0=100.$

Ten in base $100$: $(10)_{100}=1(100)+0=10$.

This should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: In base $r$, you need digits for each of the numbers $0, \ldots, r - 1$, and in base $r^2$ you need digits $0, \ldots, r^2 - 1$. How you express $r^2 - 1$ in base $r$?

Comment: I like this answer. You pointed out something important in terms of symbolism, I think. I wish the $9+10=21$ absurdity problem would stay open because I think I provided a nice answer that addresses what you brought up about base digits (in the link, only base $8$ would make sense but we have $9$ so base $8$ won't work; thus, $9+10=21$ is nonsense when all of the numbers are expressed in the same base): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122779/can-910-equal-21/1122804#1122804